# Dynamic Datatable using Yajra

Tags: jquery, datatable, laravel-5.1

I am trying to create a server side datatable in Laravel 5.1. I successfully created it using Yajra but it would be better if I can create it dynamically, so that if i add any new column in the table it can automatically render it.

Is it possible with Yajra? Or i need to use some other datatable package?

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: How is jquery related with this?

Comment: Because datatables is a plug-in for the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem just achieved the result after 2 days of trying here is the solution:

```
$dt = Datatables::of($model);
if ($request->has('field') {
  $dt->addColumn($field, 'content here');
}

return $dt->make(true);
```

Regards :)